# Mutating several columns with different functions simultaneously

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Consider the following table:

```
df <- tibble(
  col1 = sample(10:1000, 5),
  col2 = sample(1000:10000, 5),
  col3 = sample(100:500, 5)
)
```

I'd like to divide `col1` and `col3` by 10, and `col2` by 1000.

I can do this by using 2 `mutate_at` functions like so:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(
    c("col1", "col3"),
    ~ .x / 10
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(
    "col2",
    ~ .x / 1000
  )
```

Is there a way to do the above in a single `mutate_x` function?

Comment: In the next release of `dplyr`, you could use `across` and do this with one `mutate`. `df %>%
  mutate(across(col1, col2), ~.x/10, 
         across(col3), ~.x/1000)
` . See here https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ronak says, `across` will replace the scoped verbs `_at`, `_if`, `_all` in the newest version of `dplyr`. You can start using it prior to its CRAN release by doing `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`.

The correct use of `across` is slightly different than in his comment above.

```r
df %>% mutate(across(c(col1, col2), ~.x/10), 
              across(col3, ~.x/1000))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  87.3  127. 0.324
#> 2  19.5  752. 0.194
#> 3  74.3  972. 0.197
#> 4  42.5  258. 0.116
#> 5  88.6  749. 0.11
```